# Converting generic method to async causing issues with generic params

Tags: c#, .net, generics, async-await, task-parallel-library

In a static class called `StaticHelper`, I have the following generic `static` method:

```
public static class StaticHelper
{
    public static TResponse GenericMethod<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest request,
                                                           Func<TRequest, TResponse> method)
    where TRequest  : BaseRequest
    where TResponse : BaseResponse, new()
{
    // ...
}
```

`Func<TRequest, TResponse> method` is the name of the method that gets invoked by `GenericMethod`. `GenericMethod` is used as a wrapper around WCF methods to log requests/responses, etc:

```
public override SomeCustomResponse Request(SomeCustomRequest request)
{
    // GenericMethod above called here
    return StaticHelper.GenericMethod(request, ExecuteRequest));
}

private SomeCustomResponse ExecuteRequest(SomeCustomRequest request)
{
    // ...
}
```

I am now trying to create it's `async` equivalent:

```
public static async Task<TResponse> GenericMethodAsync<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest request,
                                                           Func<TRequest, TResponse> method)
    where TRequest  : BaseRequest
    where TResponse : BaseResponse, new()
{
    // ...
}

// i have removed the override keyword here as I don't need it
public async Task<SomeCustomResponse> Request(SomeCustomRequest request)
{
    // GenericMethodAsync above called here
    return await StaticHelper.GenericMethodAsync(request, ExecuteRequest));
}

private async Task<SomeCustomResponse> ExecuteRequest(SomeCustomRequest request)
{
    // ...
}
```

This ends up in two errors:

In `public async Task<SomeCustomResponse> Request(SomeCustomRequest request)` (2nd async method):

> 1) The type `Task<SomeCustomResponse>` cannot be used as type parameter '`TResponse`' in the generic type or method '`StaticHelper.GenericMethodAsync<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest, Func<TRequest, TResponse>)`'. There is no implicit reference conversion from `Task<SomeCustomResponse>` to `BaseResponse`

...and:

> 2) `Task<SomeCustomResponse>` must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter '`TResponse`' in the generic type or method `StaticHelper.GenericMethodAsync<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest, Func<TRequest, TResponse>)`

Update: The answer by René below makes the errors disappear. I now have a new one:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`Task<TResponse>`' to '`TResponse`'

The offending line is in `StaticHelper.GenericMethodAsync` which tries to execute the `Func`:

```
var response = method(request); // <-- Cannot implicitly convert type 'Task<TResponse>' to 'TResponse'
```

...and obviously, the solution is to simply `await` that:

```
var response = await method(request);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the declaration of `GenericMethodAsync`, because the return type of the `method` (`ExecuteRequest`) now is `Task<TResponse>` instead of `TResponse`:

```
public static async Task<TResponse> GenericMethodAsync<TResponse, TRequest>(
                     TRequest request,
                     Func<TRequest, Task<TResponse>> method) // <-- change here
                            where TRequest  : BaseRequest
                            where TResponse : BaseResponse, new()
{
    // ...
}
```

And consider to rename `ExecuteRequest` to `ExecuteRequestAsync`, too.

And of course you have to change the use of `method` inside `GenericMethodAsync` now accordingly:

```
var response = await method(request);
```

Comment: @globetrotter if you use `await` you receive the object that the method from the Task returns `<TResponse>`.  If you use a simple assignment `=` you receive the Task in question `Task<TResponse>` the return value can then be accessed via [task.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MongZhu Since OP made `GenericMethodAsync` an `async` method, it's a probably a bad idea to block it with `task.Result` instead of awaiting the task.

Comment: I did not intend to suggest using `Result`. Merely explained a way to access the returning value.